# SQL Query to Calculate the Rolling Difference by Date

Tags: sql-server, date

I cannot seem to work this one out to be exactly what need.

I'm using MS SQL Management Studio 2008.

I have a table (several actually) but lets keep it simple. The table contains daily stock figures for each item (SKU).

```
SKU DataDate               Web_qty
2   2014-11-17 00:00:00    404
2   2014-11-18 00:00:00    373
2   2014-11-19 00:00:00    1350
66  2014-11-17 00:00:00    3624
66  2014-11-18 00:00:00    3576
66  2014-11-19 00:00:00    3570
67  2014-11-17 00:00:00    9353
67  2014-11-18 00:00:00    9297
67  2014-11-19 00:00:00    9250
```

I simply need the Select Query to return this:

```
SKU DataDate               Difference
2   2014-11-17 00:00:00    ---
2   2014-11-18 00:00:00    -31
2   2014-11-19 00:00:00    +977
66  2014-11-17 00:00:00    ---
66  2014-11-18 00:00:00    -48
66  2014-11-19 00:00:00    -6
67  2014-11-17 00:00:00    ---
67  2014-11-18 00:00:00    -56
67  2014-11-19 00:00:00    -47
```

I do not need the --- parts, I have just shown that to draw attention to the fact that this one cannot be calculated as it is the first record.

I've tried using derived tables, but its getting a little confusing, i need to play with a working example so I can understand it better.

If someone could point me in the right direction I'm sure I'll be able to join the other tables back together (i.e. SKU Description and prices).

Really appreciate everyone's time

Kev

Comment: Does `Datadate` always be continuous for each `SKU`?

Comment: Yes, once an SKU is added to the SKU table then each day a stock figure is added to the stock table even if the value does not change in the period.
Actually I also do this for the pricing table. I need to change this as the table is getting very large but has very few changes. I need to create prices within a date range :)

Comment: @Jaugar Chang, I see what you were getting at now! If you have more than one Web_Qty for a particular date (say two quantity updates for 2014-11-18) then the query will error as it will return two values and not know which to subtract from 2014-11-19 value. I'll make a note in the answer below to inform others.

Comment: If there are more than one Web_Qty a day, you could sum Web_Qty before calculate difference. My concern is if `Datadate` are not continuous such as `11-17` , `11-19`(no record for `11-18`). What will be the difference of `11-19`? The Web_Qty of `11-19` or the Web_Qty's difference between  `11-19` and `11-17`?

Comment: Yes of course this is another possibility of this solution...
My problem is solved though, I did not have any of these issue, changed your query to an update query and added a column to my table. Now I calculate this on the fly when storing my daily stock figure so actually do not need to execute the query again.
Thanks for your help, you are extremely helpful and its been appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Use `correlated sub-query` to find `rolling difference`

```
CREATE TABLE #tem
  (SKU      INT,DataDate DATETIME,Web_qty  INT)

INSERT #tem
VALUES( 2,'2014-11-17 00:00:00',404),
       (2,'2014-11-18 00:00:00',373),
       (2,'2014-11-19 00:00:00',1350),
       (66,'2014-11-17 00:00:00',3624),
       (66,'2014-11-18 00:00:00',3576),
       (66,'2014-11-19 00:00:00',3570),
       (67,'2014-11-17 00:00:00',9353),
       (67,'2014-11-18 00:00:00',9297),
       (67,'2014-11-19 00:00:00',9250)

SELECT *,
       Web_qty - (SELECT Web_qty
                  FROM   #tem a
                  WHERE  a.sku = b.SKU
                         AND a.DataDate = Dateadd(dd, -1, b.DataDate)) Roll_diff
FROM   #tem b
```

Comment: Perfect example for me, thanks, my problem is solved.

Comment: NOTE:  This is a great example and worked for what I needed.
However, its limited in terms that it must have only "ONE" Web_Qty per Date. Otherwise it will throw an error because the sub query returns more than one value.

Comment: @Kev In that case what is your expected output.

Comment: Hi, actually for me I "should" not have this situation. Although due to testing I corrupted my data :(.  If I did have this though I would probably use a Min (in my situation) to bring back just one figure rather than error?

Answer (score 2):

I know it is an old thread but I happened to have a similar problem and I ended up solving it with Window functions. It works in SQL 2014 but not sure about 2008.

It also solves the problem of potentially non-continuous data as well as rows with no changes. Hopefully it helps someone out there!

```
CREATE TABLE #tem
(SKU INT,DataDate DATETIME,Web_qty INT)

INSERT #tem
VALUES( 2,'2014-11-17 00:00:00',404),
   (2,'2014-11-18 00:00:00',373),
   (2,'2014-11-19 00:00:00',1350),
   (2,'2014-11-20 00:00:00',1350),
   (2,'2014-11-21 00:00:00',1350),
   (66,'2014-11-17 00:00:00',3624),
   (66,'2014-11-18 00:00:00',3576),
   (66,'2014-11-19 00:00:00',3570),
   (66,'2014-11-20 00:00:00',3590),
   (66,'2014-11-21 00:00:00',3578),
   (67,'2014-11-17 00:00:00',9353),
   (67,'2014-11-18 00:00:00',9297),
   (67,'2014-11-19 00:00:00',9250),
   (67,'2014-11-20 00:00:00',9250),
   (67,'2014-11-21 00:00:00',9240)

;WITH A AS (
SELECT 
  SKU,
  DataDate,
  Web_Qty,
  Web_qty - LAG(Web_qty,1, 0)
    OVER (PARTITION BY SKU ORDER BY DataDate) Roll_diff
FROM #tem b 
)
SELECT
  SKU,
  DataDate ValidFromDate,
  Lead(DataDate, 1, DateFromParts(9999,12,31))  OVER (PARTITION BY SKU ORDER BY DataDate) ValidToDate,
  Web_Qty
FROM A WHERE Roll_diff <> 0
```

Comment: Much better solution than the other one in my opinion and exactly what I was looking for, thank you.