# Is it possible to do Week to Week comparison for different years without using join in SQL?

Tags: sql, join, amazon-redshift

Now I have a table, let called it table a, and it is  as follows

```
Country    date        year   week   visits   orders   CVR_visitToOrder
   US      2018-08-05  2018   33     1000     100      0.1
   DE      2018-08-05  2018   33     1500     150      0.1
   US      2017-08-06  2017   33     1200     60       0.05
   DE      2017-08-06  2017   33     800      20       0.025
```

Now I want to compare the conversion rate for the same calendar week between different year. So what I do is, I use a with statement to join itself again and see the difference like

```
With a as (
  Select 
    Country,date,year,week,visits,orders,CVR_visitToOrder
  FROM
    db.table
)

SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  a
LEFT JOIN a as a1
  ON a.Country = a1.Country 
  AND a.week = a1.week
  AND a.year = a1.year - 1
```

To optimize the query, if I want to make it more direct i.e like the vlookup function, look up the same week in last year and return the visit, orders and CVR, is there any other alternative method to do so? 
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need a **rolling difference** similar with question below:

Try this. Use correlated sub-query to find rolling difference

```
CREATE TABLE #tem
  (SKU      INT,DataDate DATETIME,Web_qty  INT)

INSERT #tem
VALUES( 2,'2014-11-17 00:00:00',404),
       (2,'2014-11-18 00:00:00',373),
       (2,'2014-11-19 00:00:00',1350),
       (66,'2014-11-17 00:00:00',3624),
       (66,'2014-11-18 00:00:00',3576),
       (66,'2014-11-19 00:00:00',3570),
       (67,'2014-11-17 00:00:00',9353),
       (67,'2014-11-18 00:00:00',9297),
       (67,'2014-11-19 00:00:00',9250)

SELECT *,
       Web_qty - (SELECT Web_qty
                  FROM   #tem a
                  WHERE  a.sku = b.SKU
                         AND a.DataDate = Dateadd(dd, -1, b.DataDate)) Roll_diff
FROM   #tem b
```

[SQL Query to Calculate the Rolling Difference by Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26988679/sql-query-to-calculate-the-rolling-difference-by-date)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what "conversation rate" means in your data.  But the answer to your question is that you can use window functions.

For example, to get the previous year's visits:

```
select country, year, visits, week,
       lag(visits) over (partition by country, week order by year) as prev_visits
from t;
```

This assumes that all weeks are available in all years.

If you want to compare two particular years, then conditional aggregation is another possibility.